# Asking same question from another sister site

Tags: discussion

I asked this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102442/finding-infeasible-sets-of-constraints-csp), but I am yet to get a satisfactory answer. Now apparently, the current site is more focused on this type of questions than the cs.stackexchange, does it make sense if I ask the same question here again (and possibly put hyperlink to connect the two questions)?

Answer (score 6):

I think this should only be done if *both* of the following conditions apply

1. You have provided enough feedback on answers/comments you have received to make it clear *to the people who gave the answers/comments* why they do not solve your problem.
2. It is clear *to you* that the other site is not able to provide you a suitable answer after making an effort to fully explain your problem (which should be clear after having exhausted part 1 and seeing no satisfying answer after a week or so)

I'd like to emphasize part 1, because (for me) a key part of no cross-posting rule is that it should not be misused to simply gain a larger audience for your question at the expense of the community where you initially posted your question. If you have not explained why the answers received are not helpful for you, then why would you conclude that community cannot solve your problem? At the very least, I don't think you've given them a fair chance.

---

As for your specific question, it seems that you have received an answer and a relevant comment, but have provided no feedback whatsoever. I'm of the opinion that condition 1 is not satisfied here. From my understanding of your question, both the comment and answer you have received are at least a possible approach or a step to a solution. (note that the equality constraints over binary variables you describe can be expressed as a SAT instance) If this will not work for you or you want more details, you should *ask* for them.

I suggest that you try to engage with the attempts at a solution that has been offered to you, instead of ignoring them and getting a solution elsewhere.

---

For completeness, I will note here that I am currently a moderator on CS.SE. However, I think that the conditions I give above should apply regardless of the SE site the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can post the question here. If you leave it up on CS, too, then I would add a link on each post to the other. And, if someone here answers your question in a satisfactory manner, make sure to close the post on CS so no one wastes effort answering a question you already have an answer to; and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the exact circumstance.

**If you're posting the *exact* same question hoping to get the *exact* same answers,** then just post it on one site. It's easier to maintain if all answers are kept in one place, which is the reason we close certain questions as duplicates. There's just no feature to mark questions as cross-site duplicates.

**If the question is similar but different or looking for a different *perspective* on the issue,** then it's okay to post the question on multiple sites.

In your example, you're likely going to get answers that give you more of the computer science perspective on the issue on CS.SE, but if you post here on OR.SE, you'll likely get answers explaining more of the *mathematical* concept of the question. So I do think you can cross-post your question on CS to OR if you want both the computer science part and the mathematical part in detail. Just remember to link them to each other.

There's also a [FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069) outlining when and how you can cross-post to multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give the general rule.  For that specific question, I think it is very much in keeping with OR-SE and makes a very good example of what the site can handle well, in keeping with the goals of the Private Beta phase.